# Install libssh include libsshpp.hpp

Tags: c++, libssh

I'm writing a C++ program using libssh so I look around to install the library. At first I install by `sudo apt-get install libssh-dev` but there's no libsshpp.hpp in /usr/include/libssh.

Then I clone `git://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git libssh` in ~ directory and run `./build/build_make.sh`, it has libsshpp.hpp in `~/libssh/include` but not in `/usr/include/libssh`.

I think it's because different version between them, the newer have libsshpp.hpp, I then try to copy file libsshpp.hpp to `/usr/include/libssh` but there's many error when I compile example libsshpp.cpp in examples folder so I think this is not solution.

My question is how can I install newest version of libssh and automatically add headers to `/usr/include/libssh` not only in its own install folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that, you can modify **include/libssh/CMakeLists.txt** and add

```
libsshpp.hpp
```

to the **libssh_HDRS** variable. Because it's not installed by default, this may be not supported officially.

Comment: Please open a bug at https://red.libssh.org/ that we install the header file in future! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off not using the code from the git repository for the reason that those headers won't match the code for `libssh` that's actually installed on your system.

So I'd recommend reversing the changes you made (delete the files or symlinks you copied or created) and instead installing the development parts using `apt`.  You can find out which header files were installed by doing this:

```
rpm -ql libssh-dev
```

On my system (Fedora) the package is actually called `libssh-devel`.  When I run

```
rpm -ql libssh-devel
```

I get the following output (partial)

```
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h
/usr/include/libssh/legacy.h
/usr/include/libssh/libssh.h
/usr/include/libssh/server.h
/usr/include/libssh/sftp.h
/usr/include/libssh/ssh2.h
/usr/lib64/cmake/libssh-config-version.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/libssh-config.cmake
/usr/lib64/libssh.so
/usr/lib64/libssh_threads.so
    ...
```

As you can see, the `libssh.h` header is in the `libssh` directory, so from your code you'd use

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
```

Using that method will better assure that the headers you have installed will match the libraries you have installed and save many frustrating hours later.

Here's a quick test program you can use to make sure it's really working:

```
// sshtest.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ssh_copyright() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, link and run:

g++ -o sshtest sshtest.cpp -lssh
./sshtest

This should produce the copyright string which starts with the `libssh` version number so you can verify that it matches the version you expected.

On my machine just now, that produced the following output:

```
0.6.3 (c) 2003-2014 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider, and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can install the library with

```
apt-get install libssh-dev
```

Then, if you're compiling manually use `-lssh` to link the library eg.

```
gcc -lssh ssh-program.c
```